# Why can't choose the DropDownList item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

When I use FineUI DropDownList to achieve a tree.
Page source code like these:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <FineUI:PageManager runat="server" id="PageManager1"></FineUI:PageManager>
        <FineUI:SimpleForm ID="SimpleForm1" BodyPadding="5px" runat="server" LabelWidth="150px" Width="550px" EnableCollapse="true"
            ShowBorder="True" Title="Simple Form" ShowHeader="True">
            <Items>
                <FineUI:DropDownList Label="Simulation tree DropDownList" AutoPostBack="false" Required="true" EnableSimulateTree="true"
                    ShowRedStar="true" runat="server" ID="ddlBox">
                </FineUI:DropDownList>
                <FineUI:Button ID="Button1" Text="Show Selected Item" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click">
                </FineUI:Button>
                <FineUI:Label runat="server" ID ="result" Label ="select items"></FineUI:Label>
            </Items>
        </FineUI:SimpleForm> 
    </div>
    </form>
```

At the page_load() event finish the DropDownList's data binding. Event code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        binddata();
    }
}
public class JQueryFeature
{
    private string _id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    private int _level;
    public int Level
    {
        get { return _level; }
        set { _level = value; }
    }
    private bool _enableSelect;
    public bool EnableSelect
    {
        get { return _enableSelect; }
        set { _enableSelect = value; }
    }
    public JQueryFeature(string id, string name, int level, bool enableSelect)
    {
        _id = id;
        _name = name;
        _level = level;
        _enableSelect = enableSelect;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name:{0}+Id:{1}", Name, Id);
    }
}
private void binddata()
{ 
    List<JQueryFeature> mylist= new List<JQueryFeature>();
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("0", "jQuery", 0, false));
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("1", "core", 1, false));
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("2", "Select", 1, false));
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("3", "Base Select", 2, true));
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("4", "Content Select", 2, true));
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("5", "Property Select", 2, true));
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("6", "Sift", 1, false));
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("7", "Filtration", 2, true));
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("8", "Search", 2, true));
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("9", "Event", 1, false));
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("10", "Page_load", 2, true));
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("11", "Event_deal", 2, true));
    mylist.Add(new JQueryFeature("12", "Event_authorize", 2, true));
    ddlBox.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlBox.DataValueField = "Id";
    ddlBox.DataSimulateTreeLevelField = "Level";
    ddlBox.DataEnableSelectField = "EnableSelect";
    ddlBox.DataSource = mylist;
    ddlBox.DataBind();
}
```

When I finish these codes. DropDownList can show the data, but there is a problem I can't choose  any item in the list. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What happens when you try to select the item in the list? Does selection go off? Any error? Are you not able to get the selected item in the code behind? Please explain the behaviour you are currently getting what is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting DropDownList's SelectedValue. At the end of binddata()event add this code: ddlBox.SelectedValue = "3"; Problem will solve.